# I'm trying to return back a static data from a query in the resolver

Tags: node.js, typescript, graphql, nestjs

I'm using nestjs and graphql to implement this.
Here is whats inside the service of a source, I created an array of objects to retrieve them through the function getAllPromotions():

```
@ObjectType("Promotions")
export class StaticPromotions{
    @Field(() => String, { description: "Id of the promotion"})
    id: string;

    @Field(() => String, { description: "Image of the item"})
    image: string;

    @Field(() => String, { description: "Name of the item"})
    itemName: string;

    @Field(() => String, { description: "Name of the store"})
    storeName: string;

    @Field(() => String, { description: "The id of the store"})
    storeID: string;

    @Field(() => String, { description: "The offer of the promotion"})
    offer: string;
};

@Injectable()
export class PromotionService {
    private staticPromotions: StaticPromotions[] = [
        {
            id: 'dfdv',
            image: 'assets/images/download.jpg',
            itemName : 'Chicken Salad',
            storeName : 'Sufi',
            storeID : 'CCVV',
            offer : 'Get 50% OFF'
        },
        {
            id: 'dwewfdv',
            image: 'assets/images/download.jpg',
            itemName : 'Chicken Salad',
            storeName : 'Sufi',
            storeID : 'CCVV',
            offer : 'Get 50% OFF'
        },
    ]
    async getAllPromotions(){
        return this.staticPromotions;
    }
```

And this is that inside the resolver of the same source:

```
@Resolver('Promotions')
export class PromotionResolver {
    constructor(
        private promotionService: PromotionService
    ){};

    @Query((returns) => [StaticPromotions])// the return type should be changed later into entity type
    @UseGuards(UserAuthStrategy)
    async allStoresForUser(
        @Context('user') user: User,
    ): Promise<StaticPromotions[]> {
        return this.promotionService.getAllPromotions(user.id);
    }
}
```

But I don't know why it keeps giving me this same error over and over although I've done this before in another resource and it worked.
Here is the Error text:

> ```
> [{
>   "resource": "whatever/promotion.resolver.ts",
>   "owner": "typescript",
>   "code": "2345",
>   "severity": 8,
>   "message": "Argument of type 'TypedPropertyDescriptor<(user: User) => Promise<StaticPromotions[]>>' is not assignable to parameter
> ```
>
> of type 'number'.",
> "source": "ts",
> "startLineNumber": 13,
> "startColumn": 6,
> "endLineNumber": 13,
> "endColumn": 44
> }]

And also I get this too:

> [{    "resource": "/whatever/promotion.resolver.ts",
> "owner": "typescript",  "code": "2769",     "severity": 8,  "message":
> "No overload matches this call.\n  Overload 1 of 3, '(...pipes:
> (PipeTransform<any, any> | Type<PipeTransform<any, any>>)[]):
> ParameterDecorator', gave the following error.\n    Argument of type
> '(returns: any) => (typeof StaticPromotions)[]' is not assignable to
> parameter of type 'PipeTransform<any, any> | Type<PipeTransform<any,
> any>>'.\n  Overload 2 of 3, '(property: string, ...pipes:
> (PipeTransform<any, any> | Type<PipeTransform<any, any>>)[]):
> ParameterDecorator', gave the following error.\n    Argument of type
> '(returns: any) => (typeof StaticPromotions)[]' is not assignable to
> parameter of type 'string'.",     "source": "ts",     "startLineNumber": 13,
> "startColumn": 12,  "endLineNumber": 13,    "endColumn": 43 }]

Please note that I don't want to use a model or a dto that's why I'm trying this way.

Answer (score 0):

Oh, my bad.
The only problem was that I imported the Query obj from '@nestjs/common' instead of importing it from '@nestjs/graphql'.
Those silly mistakes are what make people experienced.